# Where in Gnome libs, is 'True' and 'False' defined?

Tags: gnome, libraries, header-file

I'm trying to compile a program with gnome-libs, that uses `True` and `False`, in one of the arguments. But what header file defines them?

I'm getting the following error:

```
guignome/guignome.c: In function ‘gui_MenuBarEntryShown’:
guignome/guignome.c:1060: error: ‘False’ undeclared (first use in this function)
[...]
guignome/guignome.c: In function ‘creategw’:
guignome/guignome.c:1309: error: ‘True’ undeclared (first use in this function)
guignome/guignome.c:1319: error: ‘False’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

This is one portion of code where this error occurs:

```
    if (optvaltext!=NULL) {
      if (strcmp(optvaltext,wme->menuentry->optvalue)) {
        gtk_menu_item_configure(GTK_MENU_ITEM(wme->menuentrywidget),ElvFalse,False);
      } else {
        gtk_menu_item_configure(GTK_MENU_ITEM(wme->menuentrywidget),ElvTrue,False);
      };

    }; /* optvaltext!=NULL */
```

The file only includes `gnome.h` and `glade.h`:

```
#include <gnome.h>
#include <glade/glade.h>
```

...well?

Comment: This almost certainly belongs on SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really meant `TRUE` and `FALSE` then /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h has

```
#ifndef FALSE
#define FALSE   (0)
#endif

#ifndef TRUE
#define TRUE    (!FALSE)
#endif
```

If you meant something else, you'll need to specify what you mean by `gnome-libs` more precisely.

### added a pretty reasonable guess

The macros you are lacking are not defined within GTK anything, and the `Elv*` booleans appear to be an enumerated type in the [Elvis Text Editor](http://elvis.the-little-red-haired-girl.org/):

```
enum {ElvFalse, ElvTrue} ELVBOOL;
```

I suspect this code was borrowed from some other codebase and lost its headers. Unsurprisingly, this makes `ElvFalse` equivalent to `0` and `ElvTrue` equal to `1` (at least in the Southern Hemisphere, I hear things are backwards up North).

Given the prototype:

```
void gtk_menu_item_configure(GtkMenuItem *menu_item,
         gint show_toggle_indicator,
         gint show_submenu_indicator);
```

the values 0 and 1 seem like pretty good guesses as to the value of the constants.

### added in response to comment

From elvis-2.2_0/doc/bugs.txt:

> / Elvis' BOOLEAN and data type may clash with a standard one.  Change its
>     name, and the names of the True and False values.

Where the `/` is the author's flag "that I believe it has
been solved." Which is peculiar when there appears

```
... ElvFalse,False)
```

in the code. But more troublesome still is in guignome/README.gnome (dated October 2003):

> The Gnome/GTK+ GUI extension to Elvis is being written by David Alan Gilbert
>   (elvis@treblig.org). It is very much in it's development stages!

I cannot build Elvis 2.2 on Unbuntu Maverick for different defects than you report (in `guix11`) and the latest Debian/Ubuntu repositories carry no Gnome version of elvis only X11. As the main Elvis page was last updated two years ago, I doubt the Gnome version ever worked or works with modern Gnome.

That said, there's no harm in trying

```
#define False (0)
#define True (!False)
```

but I'm not sure that will get you far.

Comment: OK, i clarified my question.

Comment: Yeah, it's Elvis I'm trying to compile, but it's not `ElvFalse` and `ElvTrue` that's causing the problems, it's `False` and `True`. Couldn't I simply reassign the values in one of the headers?

Comment: Great! that solved the issue, and I believe I'm only a few steps away from finishing the compile. `guignome/guignome.o: In function 'gui_KeyPress': guignome.c:(.text+0x2ec3): undefined reference to 'elvprint'`. I greped the whole code base for `elvprint` and there is no definition for it. Any ideas?